# Computing probabilities efficiently (involving simple numeric computation)

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I'm given an array of probabilities $p_1p_2p_3\ldots p_n$, where the $i^{th}$ entry in the array corresponds to the probability that the sun shines at the $i^{th}$ day and there are $n$ days in total. The probabilities are independent of each other. I should compute the probability that the sun shines at least on $k$ of the $n$ days. Mathematically I know how to compute this:
Let $X$ denote the number of days the sun shines. Then $$
P(X \geq    k) = 1 - P(X \leq k-1) = \sum\limits_{I = 0}^{k-1}\Gamma
$$
where $\Gamma$ for e.g. $n = 4, \space I = 2$ corresponds to all combinations of $p_1p_2p_3p_4$ where the sun shines at two days, so one of these would be $p_1\cdot p_2\cdot \bar{p}_3 \cdot \bar{p}_4$ (hopefully it's clear what I mean, the maths behind this problem are indeed not difficult). The point where I'm struggling with is how this can be computed efficiently. My approach was computing all bit strings of length $n$ with exactly $I$ $1$'s and when there is a one it means that the sun shines on that day, but for large values of $n$ this gets computationally very hard, as I'm iterating $2^n$ times for this computation. I know that this is a math forum, but unfortunately I didn't find much help on stack overflow.

Comment: I suspect there is no way to find this other than checking all the relevant subsets of days. If $n$ is very large and you can settle for an approximation you might get one by considering just the days with the largest probabilities, or grouping the probabilities into buckets (if they were all equal the problem would be easier). Perhaps if you [edit] the question to give us more context we can help.

Comment: With all $p_k$ different, there is no good way.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm not given any more context unfortunately, but the probabilities are distinct (that's what makes it computationally so hard). However, are there any other methods how I could approximate the solution?

Comment: PARI/GP might be able to help with forsubset . I believe you can  set a conditional to limit the subset size of those, then maybe parsum ?

Comment: Perhaps suppose the only values for the $p_i$ are multiples of $1/k$ for some $k << n$, and pretend each $p_i$ is actually the nearest multiple of $1/k$. See if there are tractable values of $k$ that give you good enough answers.